# Database design - Keeping track of what users visit a profile

Tags: php, sql, database-design

I currently have a table that pairs a profile id and user id to keep track of who visits a profile. I've realized that this could generate a big number of permutations depending on the number of users. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish. What do you need this logging for? Do you need details for every visit to every profile by every user or could you settle for a total number of visits to a given profile?

Comment: This is for displaying the pictures of the twelve most recent users that have visited a profile. A bit like on Netlog if you know the site. There's also a longer list showing detail. What I've done at the moment is to have a single profile id and user id pair that is either created or the timestamp updated if it already exists. If it's the number of visitors can be limited to a given number or timespan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep it in database. If you have many active users, you might want to keep such records in an another database.

You could also go with keeping them with cache in files which will take some load over CPU of your server.

Oh before I forget, keeping them even in the same database, you could put your mysql database in partitions like hard drives.

Please read this article if you want to keep them in database, this could be the solution for you [**MySQL Partitioning**](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/performance-partitioning.html)

Comment: Pixeler, I didn't know about partitioning. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Always a pleasure, hope this will solve your problems. You could check here to see how much mysql database size could be depending on OS. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html . I believe such sizes would be enough for you + partitioning will increase your project's performance.

Comment: Nope, I'm fine. Database size isn't an issue yet. An additional optimization I've thought of is to drop id pairs that are older than a month.

Comment: Cleaning up old data is always good solution but you have to be prepared. As you said database size isn't an issue YET. You have to make things ready to change the structure really fast if it is needed.